# Moving Folders and Files From a Team Site to Sub-Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, copy-and-paste, copy-content

I want to move a large volume of folders, sub-folders, and files from:
`OurURL.SharePoint.com/HQ/Working` to `OurURL.SharePoint.com/HQ/Collaborate`

I've tried to accomplish this in Windows Explorer but I keep getting an error message that it

> "Can't read from the source file or disk."

I get the same error message for Files, Sub-Folders, and main Folders.  We have over 2000+ folders to move so I need a solution.

I'm using SharePoint Online; I'm the Global Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint interface to move files and folder in same tenant.
Opening your Library (Use new experience), you have a MOVE option selecting a folder. After select the folder and click on MOVE TO, select the destination on right side.

IF this dont work for you, try to use the ShareGate or SharePoint Migration Tool (or try).

Other option is Sync the libraries using OneDrive. Map the two libraries and move the files manual, waiting the files sync.

All this options you dont need to customize anything. If you cant solve your problem, try PowerShell PnP.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

As the previous respondent has suggested, I tried to use the "Move" option and the subsite was not listed in the category of places I could move the folders.  I'm unsure why.

I did not use ShareGate or the SharePoint Migration Tool, nor did I explore how to do that.

I returned to classic view for both the site I wanted to move the folders from, and to while using IE11 and opened both sites in Windows Explorer view.  I then moved the files from site 1 to my desktop, and then moved them from the desktop to site 2.  It was just stupid how slow this method is, but it was simple, effective, trainable and repeatable.